# How to verify a img file existed before setIcon it to JLabel in case clean and build to JAR file?

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I am designing a Java program to set icon to `JLabel` when clicking the corresponding button. I want to know ways to check whether the img exists before calling:

```
ImageIcon myIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));
```

I'm not allowed to use try catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image does not exist in the supplied path, the URL returned from `getResource(..)` will be `null`.